# Databricks Job fails with 'IPythonShell' object has no attribute 'ask_exit'

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I'm bringing some data from HTTP api and I've used exit() after printing the response but not used anywhere that ask_exit() still the job is throwing the error 'IPythonShell' object has no attribute 'ask_exit'. But when I run the same code manually it is getting executed successfully. The below is the code where it is failing.

```
      if appflds_httpResponse.status_code != 200:
            print("HTTP Response Status: ", appflds_httpResponse.status_code)
            exit()
```

I'm using the below:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml
from lxml import etree
import html
import sys
from requests import status_codes
import re
from pyspark.sql import *
```

could you kindly help on this how to resolve the issue.

thank you
Amar

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `exit()`, the recommended way is to raise an exception - this will terminate job with correct exit code.  Like this:

```py
if appflds_httpResponse.status_code != 200:
  raise Exception(f"Non-200 HTTP status code: {appflds_httpResponse.status_code}")
```

Comment: Hi Alex,  Thank you for your response.  You mean after printing it raising the exception will terminate that particular portion of job and continue remaining? I will try this definitely and update.

Comment: Yes, it will terminate the job if it’s non-200 http response